# Running multiple exec commands and waiting to finish before continuing

Tags: background, tcl, exec, tk-toolkit

I know I ask a lot of questions and I know there is a lot on here about this exactly what I am trying to do but I have not been able to get it to work in my script nor figure out why it does not let me do this. I am trying to run several commands using `exec` in the background and the tests can range anywhere between 5 and 45 minutes (longer if they have to cue for a license). It takes forever to run them back to back so I was wondering what I need to do to make my script wait for them to finish before moving on the the next section of script.

```
while {$cnt <= $len} {
# Begin count for running tests
set testvar [lindex $f $cnt]
if {[file exists $path0/$testvar] == 1} {
    cd $testvar
} else {
    exec mkdir $testvar
    cd $testvar
    exec create_symobic_link_here
}
# Set up test environment
exec -ignorestderr make clean
exec -ignorestderr make depends
puts "Running $testvar"
set runtest [eval exec -ignorestderr bsub -I -q lin_i make $testvar SEED=1 VPDDUMP=on |tail -n 1 >> $path0/runtestfile &]
cd ../
incr cnt
}
```

I know there is nothing here to make the script wait for the process to finish but I have tried many different things any this is the only way I can get it to run everything. It just doesn't wait.

Comment: I'll try to look into this later, swamped right now. Just a quick note: you don't need exec to create directories or symbolic links (and doing so will probably slow the script down). Take a look at the `file mkdir` and `file link` commands, documented under `file`.

Comment: And you don't need 'eval exec'.  Just exec.

Comment: A random thought in passing: how about omitting the & at the end of the exec call?

Comment: as in not running them in the background? if I do so the tests could take 24 hours plus and I need them to be finished within an hour and a half at the longest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to modify your tests to create a "finished" file.  This file should be created whether the test completes correctly or fails.

Modify the startup loop to remove this file before starting the test:

```
 catch { file delete $path0/$testvar/finished }
```

Then create a second loop:

```
while { true } {
  after 60000
  set cnt 1 ; # ?
  set result 0
  while { $cnt <= $len } {
    set testvar [lindex $f $cnt]
    if { [file exists $path0/$testvar/finished] } {
      incr result
    }
    incr cnt
  }
  if { $result == $len } {
    break
  }
}
```

This loop as written will never exit if any one test doesn't create the 'finished' file.  So I would add in an additional stop condition (no more than one hour) to exit the loop.

Another way would be to save the process ids of the background processes in a list and then the second loop would check each process id to see if it is still running.  This method would not require any modifications to the test, but is a little harder to implement (not too hard on unix/mac, harder on windows).

**Edit: loop using process id check:**

To use process ids, the main loop needs to be modified to save the process ids of the background jobs:

Before the main loop starts, clear the process id list:

```
set pidlist {}
```

In the main loop, save the process ids from the exec command (In tcl, `[exec ... &]` returns the background process id):

```
lappend pidlist $runtest ; # goes after the exec bsub...
```

A procedure to check for the existence of a process (for unix/mac).  Tcl/Tk does not have any process control commands, so the unix 'kill' command is used.  'kill -0' on unix only checks for process existence, and does not affect the execution of the process.

```
# return 0 if the process does not exist, 1 if it does
proc checkpid { ppid } {
  set pexists [catch {exec kill -0 $ppid}]
  return [expr {1-$pexists}]
}
```

And the second loop to check to see if the tests are done becomes:

```
set tottime 0
while { true } {
  after 60000
  incr tottime 1 ; # in minutes
  set result 0
  foreach {pid} $pidlist {
    if { ! [checkpid $pid] } {
      incr result
    }
  }
  if { $result == $len } {
    break
  }
  if { $tottime > 120 } {
    puts "Total test time exceeded."
    break ; # or exit 
  }
}
```

If a test process gets hung and never exits, this loop will never exit, so a second stop condition on total time is used.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to implement this. Does it matter what is in this finished file? or does it have to be the output from the test? I need to write the output of the tests to be used later on.

Comment: No, the 'finished' file is just a flag indicating it is done, doesn't matter what's in it.  Are you running on unix or mac?  I can write up the second loop to check for process ids instead.  That might be easier than modifying the tests.

Comment: It is on unix. I like the way you have it above I just don't fully understand where in my script I should be putting this loop and what I should be using to create the `finished` file. Im still very new with tcl (about 2 weeks)

Comment: I feel like I should add that the tests themselves cannot be modified. Im looking at this now and realizing you probably meant the end of the test would create the `finished` files

Comment: Never mind I realized the tests always create a test_1.log file I can use that

Comment: All this does for me right now is timeout. Im a little confused as to how all these relate together. I cant see anything that looks for the finished file or really even says a test is running vs not.

Comment: There are two separate methods here.   The first one looks for the finished file (which would be your test_1.log file).   The second method below the bold line uses process ids and checks for running processes rather than looking for a "finished" file.

Comment: Thank you I realized my mistake there shortly after. It works perfectly for me now :)